# Eclipse indexer shows error for perfectly running c code

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse( kepler) for the development of c code. Within the code, I have some simple macro's which refers to the function's in other file (included as header). It builds and runs perfectly fine. But, eclipse editor comes up with the error symbol wherever the macro is used.

By, primary investigation, I came to know about this being the issue with the indexer. I believe, I am missing some settings in the eclipse for indexer. Anyone has clue about this?

Comment: If you open the properties for the project, look at the "C/C++ General" tab, and click on Indexer. You can then enable "Project Specific settings" for the project. Now click ON for all of the first block of indexer options. This should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above steps did not help. :(

Comment: OK, any chance you could post some code that illustrates the problem?